# Why doesn't my D3100 take photos when the built in flash is popped up?

Tags: nikon, flash, popup-flash

I have a Nikon D3100. It doesn't take pictures while the built in flash is popped up, but is working fine when the flash is down. What could be causing this?

Comment: In what mode? All automatic or Aperture/Speed priority?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the exposure settings are significantly different (darker) when the flash is up because it is expecting the flash to add a lot of light.
If the exposure settings are dark enough that the camera cannot achieve/verify focus it will not take a picture (except when set to manual focus).

Alternatively, if the camera is set to the continuous release mode it will not take a picture when the popup flash is enabled... the two functions are incompatible (pg 53 of the manual).